# SQL syntax error. 0 and 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox, syntax

Well as the title says, I have a problem with my Syntax.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'' at line 38
```

Here my code. If someone can let me know what problem is it I would be appreciate. Whenever someone starts session it shows a form with all the options listed below, then by clicking submit shows this. Doesn't matter if I change the stuff in the line 32, it always has the same problem. Hope someone can help.

```
<?php

include('test6.inc');
// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: test2.php');
}

?>

Welcome: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>


<?php

$football = isset($_POST["football"]) ? $_POST["football"] : 0;
$baseball = isset($_POST["baseball"]) ? $_POST["baseball"] : 0;
$basketball = isset($_POST["basketball"]) ? $_POST["basketball"] : 0;
$cheer = isset($_POST["cheer"]) ? $_POST["cheer"] : 0;
$xcountry = isset($_POST["xcountry"]) ? $_POST["xcountry"] : 0;
$golf = isset($_POST["golf"]) ? $_POST["golf"] : 0;
$lacrosse = isset($_POST["lacrosse"]) ? $_POST["lacrosse"] : 0;
$rodeo = isset($_POST["rodeo"]) ? $_POST["rodeo"] : 0;
$soccer = isset($_POST["soccer"]) ? $_POST["soccer"] : 0;
$tennis = isset($_POST["tennis"]) ? $_POST["tennis"] : 0;
$track = isset($_POST["track"]) ? $_POST["track"] : 0;
$volleyball = isset($_POST["volleball"]) ? $_POST["volleball"] : 0;
$wrestling = isset($_POST["wrestling"]) ? $_POST["wrestling"] : 0;
$wbasketball = isset($_POST["wbasketball"]) ? $_POST["wbasketball"] : 0;
$wcheer = isset($_POST["wcheer"]) ? $_POST["wcheer"] : 0;
$wxcountry = isset($_POST["wxcountry"]) ? $_POST["wxcountry"] : 0;
$dance = isset($_POST["dance"]) ? $_POST["dance"] : 0;
$wgolf = isset($_POST["wgolf"]) ? $_POST["wgolf"] : 0;
$wlacrosse = isset($_POST["wlacrosse"]) ? $_POST["wlacrosse"] : 0;
$wrodeo = isset($_POST["wrodeo"]) ? $_POST["wrodeo"] : 0;
$wsoccer = isset($_POST["wsoccer"]) ? $_POST["wsoccer"] : 0;
$softball = isset($_POST["softball"]) ? $_POST["softball"] : 0;
$wtennis = isset($_POST["wtennis"]) ? $_POST["wtennis"] : 0;
$wtrack = isset($_POST["wtrack"]) ? $_POST["wtrack"] : 0;
$wvolleyball = isset($_POST["wvolleyball"]) ? $_POST["wvolleyball"] : 0;
$wwrestling = isset($_POST["wwrestling"]) ? $_POST["wwrestling"] : 0;
$student_aff = isset($_POST["student_aff"]) ? $_POST["student_aff"] : 0;
$int_club = isset($_POST["int_club"]) ? $_POST["int_club"] : 0;
$hist_act = isset($_POST["hist_act"]) ? $_POST["hist_act"] : 0;
$contests = isset($_POST["contests"]) ? $_POST["contests"] : 0;
$lib_events = isset($_POST["lib_events"]) ? $_POST["lib_events"] : 0;
$vik_exch = isset($_POST["vik_exch"]) ? $_POST["vik_exch"] : 0;


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `email`(`football`,
`baseball`,
`basketball`,
`cheer`,
`xcountry`,
`golf`,
`lacrosse`,
`rodeo`,
`soccer`,
`tennis`,
`track`,
`volleyball`,
`wrestling`,
`wbasketball`,
`wcheer`,
`wxcountry`,
`dance`,
`wgolf`,
`wlacrosse`,
`wrodeo`,
`wsoccer`,
`softball`,
`wtennis`,
`wtrack`,
`wvolleyball`,
`wwrestling`,
`sudent_aff`,
`int_club`,
`hist_act`,
`contests`,
`lib_events`,
`vik_exch`) VALUES ('$football',
'$baseball',
'$basketball',
'$cheer',
'$xcountry',
'$golf',
'$lacrosse,
'$rodeo',
'$soccer',
'$tennis',
'$track',
'$volleyball',
'$wrestling',
'$wbasketball',
'$wcheer',
'$wxcountry',
'$dance',
'$wgolf',
'$wlacrosse',
'$wrodeo',
'$wsoccer',
'$softball',
'$wtennis',
'$wtrack',
'$wvolleyball',
'$wwrestling',
'$student_aff',
'$int_club',
'$hist_act',
'$contests',
'$lib_events',
'$vik_exch')") or die(mysql_error());



?>
```

Thanks

EDITED: Fixed the previous error. There is the new error.

Comment: Put the query into a variable and echo it out. I bet that there's a quote in one of the variables. You'd be better off switching to PDO or mysqli and using the parametrization functions so that all of your variables are properly escaped, which will also prevent sql injection.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last field name is missing a closing back tick. But be glad this query doesn't work, because in the hands of someone bad enough, this can wreck your database. Its so prone to injection.

```
`vik_exch)
```

And

```
'$lacrosse,
```

is missing a closing `'`

Answer (score 0):

Close quote after `vik_exch`

```
`vik_exch`) VALUES ('$football'
```